# Manhwa where the female lead is (fake) poisoned by family and wakes up at her own funeral

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, webcomics

I read a manhwa where the the female lead dies because her family poisons her. She goes back in time and in her new life she willingly gets “poisoned” and wakes up at her funeral to point out who did it

I believe someone gives her an antidote to make sure she wakes up again after being poisoned as well. I think she might be a villainess(?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[A Marriage Alliance for Revenge](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-marriage-alliance-for-revenge)?*

> Empress Olivia knows happiness is the last thing she deserves, but
> when she finally becomes pregnant with the emperor’s child, she thinks
> things might finally be taking a turn for the better. Alas, Olivia
> realizes how naive she was when her husband poisons her tea, killing
> both her and their unborn child. When Olivia opens her eyes again in
> the body of an unknown woman in the slums, she vows to take vengeance
> against the emperor. To do so, she forms a marriage alliance with her
> former fiancé, Duke Lucas Viterpan, the true heir to the empire who
> was deposed in a coup. Will this man and woman who had everything
> taken from them succeed in getting revenge?
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is possibly this manhwa.
[image: I dream of health, wealth and a long life]

https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-dream-of-health-wealth-and-a-long-life
Synopsis : Lady Adrianna isn't just a noblewoman, she's the side character in "Ramona's Tale," the favorite novel of an ill peasant girl who died tragically young. This is her second chance at life, and she's not reliving that tragedy! An evil stepmother's not gonna stop her, and Rian slowly gathers handsome companions along the way... the calculating imperial prince, the friendly count, the mysterious and brooding demon prince. After all, she is determined to live a long, healthy, and wealthy life!

The girl actually did die but she was just a side character in the novel fl read in past life. After processing her body, fl plans to get poisoned again but takes the antidote so that her evil stepmother and stepsister are exposed at her funeral.